# How to select the second child using parent JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure

```
<div class="a">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="proccesing-btn-down">...</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="proccesing-btn-up" style="display: none;">...</button>
</div
```

I have an `onclick` function that while clicking on the `proccesing-btn-down`
I want to hide the up button and show the down one.

```
$(this).hide();
var btn = $(this).parent().$("#proccesing-btn-up");
$(btn).show();
```

hiding this - is working.
what is the problem on the second and third line?

Comment: `$(this).parent().$("#proccesing-btn-up");` isn't valid jQuery. Do you mean `$(this).siblings(selector)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are the only elements in the div you can do the following:

```
$('.btn.btn-default').on('click', function(){
  $(this).hide().siblings().show();
}):
```

**[FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/81vabey3/)**

If they aren't you ll have to pass the selector to `siblings('.btn')` to learn more check out the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: missing `$()`... `$(this)`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$(this).hide();
$(this).siblings().show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Closest will look for closest in dom elements with class.

```
$(this).hide();
var btn = $(this).closest('.a').find("#proccesing-btn-up");
$(btn).show();
```